# Synchronise two radio button values with two values of select

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button, synchronize

I have a radio button with two possibility like following :

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="first">
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="second">
```

And i would like to synchronise with the following select :

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="">Null default value</option>
<option>First value in select</option>
<option>Second value in select</option>
</select>
```

So 
- when i check first in radio button i would like that first element is automatically selected.
- when i check second in radio button i would like that second element is automatically selected.

Besides, i would like to reset all values (of select and radiobutton) if an other select like following :

```
<select name="myresetselect">
<option value="">Null default value</option>
<option>First value in select</option>
<option>Second value in select</option>
</select>
```

...has first ('Null default value') selected.

Comment: So, where actually you are getting the issue? Is the `.change()` method not working or else?

Answer (score 1):

add same value to selects option as it is in radio.. and this should work.

try this

**html**

```
<select name="myselect">
  <option value="">Null default value</option>
  <option value="first">First value in select</option> //value should always be same as radios value
  <option value="second">Second value in select</option>
 </select>
```

**jquery**

```
 $('input[name="radiobutton"]').click(function(){
     var val=$(this).val();
     $('select[name="myselect"]').val(val);
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhK6u/)

[fiddle with reset button](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/fhK6u/2/)

not sure why you need reset select while you can use simple button...

eg:

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="resetbutton"/>

$('#resetbutton').click(function(){
 $('select[name="myselect"]').val("");
 $('input[name="radiobutton"]').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, bu my problem is value are not the same, i want first element and second element of the Choice list

Comment: ok you saying the first radio should select the first option, and second the second one... if you want as such then you can use `eq()`

Comment: try this..using eq() .. http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/fhK6u/3/ .. though this is not a good solution if you have lots of radios and select